# How to add JSON data to HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to transfer the data in my JSON file across to my HTML file, so when it comes to editing data I can just have the one file open, rather than editing 20 separate files.

In this instance, the manager's name and the world ranking should appear on the HTML page using the data in the JSON file. For example, the HTML page should read: "Manager: Corinne Diacre", "World Ranking: 5".

Is this possible? If so, how do I solve this issue?

nations_women JSON file:

```
{
  "france": [
    {
      "manager": "Corinne Diacre",
      "world-ranking": "5",
    }
  ],
  "england": [
    {
      "manager": "Phil Neville",
      "world-ranking": "2",
    }
  ]
}
```

france_women HTML file:

```html
    <div>
      <h1>France Women</h1>
      <p>Manager: *NAME HERE*</p>
      <p>World Ranking: *RANKING HERE*</p>
    </div>
```

I expect it to appear "Corinne Diacre" where *NAME HERE* is and "5" where *RANKING HERE* is.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use JavaScript to parse the JSON to an object, then write some code to get values from the object and insert them into the DOM in the necessary place

Comment: @ADyson Can I have an example of this please? I am fairly inexperienced in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prerequisites:**

> - Install [`NodeJS`](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
> - Install [`this npm package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to make a simple server for serving up your local files
>
>   `npm install -g http-server`
> - Navigate to your directory `M:/Website` were your index.html is located and open a command prompt and type the following command.
>
>   `http-server --cors=*`
> - Doing that will spawn a simple HTTP server with CORS disabled.

---

Make an asynchronous call to read your `nations_women.json` file, then get the appropriate DOM elements and substitute the values in that.

In your Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {

    const franceMgrEle = document.querySelector('#franceMgr');
    const franceRanking = document.querySelector('#franceRanking');

    function readLocalFile(callback) {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                const fileContents = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                callback(fileContents);
            }
        };

        xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/nations_women.json", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        xhr.send();
    }

    function SubstituteNames(data) {
        // Substitute the value here
        franceMgrEle.innerHTML = data.france[0]['manager'];
        franceRanking.innerHTML = data.france[0]["world-ranking"];
    }

    readLocalFile(SubstituteNames);
};
```

In your HTML:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>France Women</legend>
  <span> Manager: <p id="franceMgr"></p> </span>
  <span> World Ranking: <p id="franceRanking"></p> </span>
</fieldset>
```

Your JSON file:

```
{
    "france": [{
        "manager": "Corinne Diacre",
        "world-ranking": "5"
    }],
    "england": [{
        "manager": "Phil Neville",
        "world-ranking": "2"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have copied what you have coded but I cannot seem to get the data to appear on the HTML page.

Comment: where is your `nations_women.json` file ?

Comment: They are all in the same folder.

Comment: No it is still not working! Sorry I am really bad at this!

Comment: @strong-highway try now

Comment: Unfortunately not sorry!

Comment: check what is displayed in the browser console

Comment: Nothing as such. There is just white space underneath "Manager" where the data should be

Comment: @strong-highway Kunal is asking about the Console, not the page itself. In most browsers you press F12 to open the Developer Tools, and the Console is one of the tools within that. It will show any script errors which might be preventing the code from executing properly. This is your primary debugging tool when working with JavaScript. You need to learn to use it, so you can see problems and diagnose them more easily. Most browser vendors provide online documentation about their tools, so you can learn to use them

Comment: Okay sorry! The error message I am getting is: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///M:/Website/nations_women.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: @strong-highway, please try with updated instructions

Comment: It's working thank you! Is that the only way possible?

Comment: @strong-highway Local AJAX calls in Chrome are not supported due to same-origin-policy.
If you check console logs you will find `"Cross origin requests are not supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."` that's why I made a local server with the `http-server` npm package which spawns a http server which listens on port 8080 by default. That's why you should always files using a server REST api like php, java, c#, node js etc because Javascript does not have the security permissions to access local client's drive.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee great answer, except that specifying `xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');` is total nonsense. These are response headers which must be set by the **server**, in order to tell the browser which sites are allowed to make CORS requests to it. If the client could set these headers in the request to whatever value they like, then logically they are pointless because they would not providing the server any security. You can remove these lines: they make no sense and they don't do anything